# How to declare destructor of a templated class

Tags: c++

I get error while trying to compile following class

Stack.cpp:28: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘::’ token

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack(): head(NULL) {};
    ~Stack();

    void push(T *);
    T* pop();

protected:
    class Element {
    public:
            Element(Element * next_, T * data_):next(next_), data(data_) {}
            Element * getNext() const { return next; }
            T * value() const {return data;}
    private:
            Element * next;
            T * data;
    };

    Element * head;
};

Stack::~Stack()
{
    while(head)
    {
            Element * next = head->getNext();
            delete head;
            head = next;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are declaring a template class. You can either:

- implement the destructor *within* the class declaration, like this

  ```
  public:
      Stack(): head(NULL) {};
      ~Stack() {
          // ...
      }
  ```
- define the templated destructor outside the class declaration, like this

  ```
  template <class T>
  Stack<T>::~Stack()
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```

However, if you attempt to define just `Stack::~Stack()` then the compiler does not know which type `T` you are implementing the destructor for.

Answer (score 7):

```
template<typename T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    //...
}
```

This is generally valid for every method you define outside of the class' declaration, not just the destructor.

Answer (score 5):

```
 Stack::~Stack()
```

should be

```
template <typename T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you put the function after the class definition, you must specify the template aspect again as in:

```
template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    ...
}
```

You don't need to do that if you define the function inside the class (but that constitutes a compiler hint to inline the function which you may or may not care about).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but maybe this way...

`template <class T>`

`Stack<T>::~Stack()`

Comment: While your answer is correct, if you aren't sure then you probably should not be posting an answer.